# making arduino receive data from nRF24 (SPI and nRF libraries) while reading the serial port waiting for a data request using serialcommand

Tags: arduino

I am able to transfer data from one arduino to another using nRF24L01 chips. However, I need the data to be sent ONLY when a specific command is sent on the serial port. I want to be able to write 'A' on the serial port, and for arduino to reply with the latest data. This is easy with the serialcommand library and works if I am directly plugged in. However, the moment I add the nRF24L01 module, serialcommand.h does not respond with the data anymore. I tried even removing the if (radio.available()) .. so no data would be received and just the fact that there is radio.begin() in setup makes the serialcommand 'A' not work. when I remove the radio stuff, the command 'A' does reply with three zeros (default data).

Here is my receiver code. I still consider myself a beginner and i never formally studied C/C++. Any help or ideas as to why this happens is very appreciated!

```
.
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <SerialCommand.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

SerialCommand sCmd;

RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN

const byte address[6] = "00001";

int Array[3];

void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600);
sCmd.addCommand("A", serialdataPrint );
radio.begin();
radio.setRetries(15, 15);
radio.openReadingPipe(0,address); 
radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
radio.startListening();

}

void loop() {

   while (Serial.available() > 0){
    sCmd.readSerial();

    if (radio.available()) {

    int Array_received[3];

    radio.read(&Array_received, sizeof(Array_received));

    Array[0] = Array_received[0];
    Array[1] = Array_received[1];
    Array[2] = Array_received[2];
    } 
  }
}


void serialdataPrint ()
{
    Serial.println(Array[0]);
    Serial.println(Array[1]);
    Serial.println(Array[2]);
}
```